# Dynamic Layout for the iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view, subview

I am programming a kind of dynamic worksheet for the ipad with tasks and subtasks. (for my thesis)
Tasks and subtasks can be for example making a video or drawing sth...
(I get the tasks out of a json file)

My question now is, what is the best way to program this list of tasks?
Like on the screenshoot...[image: My tasks]

My idea was to create for every kind of task a seperate view and add all the views (tasks) to the main view. But can I set the position for every subview?

Or is it posible to create a UITableView and add the subtasks into a cell?
 Or is there another posible way to do this?
Best regards
MeMa

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SplitViewController` for this IPad Screen

Comment: for the left and right thing I used the SplitviewController. But my question is how to implement  description subtask1 and subtask2

Comment: Make two arrays taskArray and subTaskarray and save the task in taskArray and subTask in subTaskArray then on the click of Task you will get the indexpath.row from task table and you can get the data from subtaskArray according to this indexpath on detailViewController